# Is there a way to redirect Log4Net output to the ASP.NET Trace listener

Tags: asp.net, log4net, trace

I have a significant amount of logging code throughout our codebase which uses log4net.  Generally this is logged to an external output file.  In this case I would like to know if there is a log4Net configuration change I could make to get this log information to show up in the ASP.NET pages trace output.

I'm just looking to redirect the output, not implement a different type of logging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the ASP.NET Trace Appender:
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.AspNetTraceAppender.html

Config example here:
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html